# How to make the Custom Share ActionSheet

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, share, uiactionsheet

How to Make the Custom Share ActionSheets with segmented Control and Share function inbuilt. Check the reference image. I try to find many library but not find perfect one.

[image]

Comment: build a view and present it modally

Comment: Hmmm. any other options?  If i present then how can i get the below export options

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLActionController allows us to create any custom action sheet giving much more flexibility than the solutions proposed above.